# Integrating twitter,facebook and other services in one single site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, twitter

I need to develop an application which should help me in getting all the status,messages from different servers like Twitter,facebook etc in my application and also when i post a message it should gets updated in all the services. I am using authlogic for authentication. Can anyone suggest me what gems/plug-ins i can use..

I need API help to get all the tweets/messages to be displayed in my application and also ways to post the messages to the corresponding services by posting it from my application. Can anyone help me from design point.

Answer (score 0):

Walk through what you'd want to do in your head.  Imagine the working site, imagine your webapp working before you start.  So your user logs in (handled by authlogic) and sees a textbox called "What are you doing right now?".  The user fills in a status message and clicks "post".  The status message appears at the top of their previously posted messages.

Start with the easy part.  Create a class that posts to two services.  Use the twitter gem and rfacebook to post to two already defined services.  In the future, you'll want to let the user associate services to their account and you would iterate through the associated services and post the message to each.  Once you have this working, you can refactor or polish the UI a bit to round out this feature.  I personally would do the "add a social media account to my profile" feature towards the end.

Harder is the reading of the data (strangely enough) because you're going to have to figure out how to store it.  You could store nothing but I suspect you'd run into API limits just searching all the time (could design around this).  I would keep a little cache of posts associated to the user's social media account.  In this way, the data model would look like this:

```
A user has many social media accounts.
A social media account has many posts. (cache)
```

Of course, now you need to schedule the caching of the posts.  This could be done manually, based on an event (like when they login) or time based.  So when the update happens, you load up the posts for that social media account and the user will see the posts the next time they hit the page.  For real-time push to the client's browser while they stare at the screen, use faye (non-trivial) and ajax to pull the new posts to the top of the social media stream view.

The time based one is tricky because you'd either have to have a cron job run or have rails handle it all with a gem like clockwork.  But then you have to leave rails running.  I've also solved this by having a class in /lib do all the work and a simple web call kicks off the update.  But it wasn't in a multi-user use case.  So that might not work.  In any case, you'll want to have some nice reusable code for these problems since update requests can come from many different sources.

You'll also have to deal with the API limits.  When pulling down content from twitter, you won't get everything.  That will just have to be known by the user or you'll have to indicate a "break in time" somehow.

The UI should be pretty easy (functionally anyway), because you know which source the post/content is coming from.  It'd be easy to throw a little icon next to the post to display which social media site it's coming from.

Anyway, good luck, sounds like a fun project.

Comment: Hey there, great answer even if it's 5 years old. I'm working on a mixed social media feed and would like to ask an additional question on this topic: Would you always recommend to save all the posts (let's say as JSON file from fb, twitter, vine and youtube API's) on your own server first, update it by Cronjob and access then that local file, instead of sending Ajax requests to the different network API's when the user opens the site? I can imagine that the first option is way faster right?

Comment: You could use a cache for this instead of thinking of it as files.  If you really want to be serving up the feed (from your server).  The problem (as you are hinting at with the cron idea) with caching is keeping it fresh or knowing when to delete it.  Cron has its own problems (it's a clock and a clock isn't a good measure of events a lot of times), for example your social network feed service might want to be the "latest things" but then it behaves like "the latest things since I refreshed an hour ago", with RSS maybe there's no other option.

Comment: I see, but if i "store" all the data first on my own server, i could eliminate the additional latency on accessing all the different API's when the page get's loaded. Right? I know that a Cronjob isn't really able to provide a Realtime Livefeed but in favor of performance, i think the user experience would be enhanced. Or is there any other way to achieve an equal performance/speed? I'm not that familiar with caching, but is there an option to fetch just the new stuff that has changed and update it to that Cache? Wich means the Users Browsercache and nothing on the serverside, right? THANKS!

Comment: There's browser data stores but I'd probably cache it on the server.  I guess you could make a completely serverless app that would do this but then you'd have to worry about memory limits and browser performance.  Plus, the browser data stores I've used are not directly comparable to server side.  They have been far simpler in my experience but I'm not a SPA/javascript authority.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for your help! Just one last question: If i use JSON files on my own server and access them on page load by the client to build the view, i could avoid, that the user sees cached deprecated pages. I see that using a http cache on the server would be the better and faster option to deliver static pages, But how could you make sure, that the user just get the cached view, when there is no new content? Or get the new content when it's needed? And if the client has to access new content really often, would a cache still beat accessing JSON files in performance?

Comment: Create a ruby class called FeedCache that implements the rules you want.  Don't optimize for performance until you've done at least one benchmark.  Create an abstraction (a class named something around your problem) on top of files and low level details.